# Self reference in Mongoid is not working in both directions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a class like:

```
class User 
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_and_belongs_to_many :following, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :followers
  has_and_belongs_to_many :followers, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :following
```

When I add a user as following another user like this:

```
  def follow id
    self.following.push User.find(id)
  end
```

following gets updated, but the "followers" reference does not for the User that is now being followed.  I'm assuming I don't have to manually push to create the inverse relationship, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you tried to add an inflection for following being its singular/plural ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using devise by any chance?  If so, you may have problems with saving the inverse user because it is missing password combination. The other user, that is, the user adding the following user is probably already authenticated and is saving fine. I discovered this problem in a similar situation myself.

I've asked another question on how to disable validation on inverse objects:
[Mongoid: disabling validation on inverse objects when saving parent for HABTM relationship Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645898/mongoid-disabling-validation-on-children-objects-when-saving-parent-for-habtm-r)